# Linking 2 object files together

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm very new to assembly programming and now I'm trying to write a program consisting of 2 object files linking together with `ld`.

1.asm

```
section .text
    global _start
    extern _print_func

_start:
    call _print_func    ; does not print anything. Why?
    call _print         ; prints Some string

    mov rax, 60
    syscall

_print:
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str
    mov rdx, [str_len]
    syscall
    ret

section .data
    str: db 'Some string',0x0A,0x0D
    str_len: db $ - str
```

2.asm

```
section .text
    global _print_func

_print_func:
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str2
    mov rdx, [str_len2]
    sycall
    ret

section .rodata
    str2: db 'Some string',0x0A,0x0D
    str_len2: db $ - str2
```

Now I'm compiling and linking them as follows

```
nasm -f elf64 1.asm
nasm -f elf64 2.asm
ld -o bin 1.o 2.o
```

After that, when I run the binary `./bin` the `call _print` succesfully prints the string while `call _print_func` linked from another module prints nothing. Why? What's wrong with that particular code?

I fixed the typo in `sycall` and now 2.asm looks as follows:

```
section .text
    global _print_func

_print_func:
;    mov rax, 0x01
;    mov rdi, 0x01
;    mov rsi, str2
;    mov rdx, [str_len2]
;    syscall
;    ret
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str2
    mov rdx, [str_len2]
    syscall
    ret

section .rodata
    str2: db 'Some string',0x0A,0x0D
    str_len2: db $ - str2
```

I also commented `1.asm` as this:

```
_start:
    call _print_func
;    call _print

    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

Now after compiling and linkinf it just prints nothing.

Comment: You are aware that `mov rdx, [str_len2]` moves 8 bytes starting at memory address `str_len2` when you have only declared a single byte there? Same with `str_len`

Comment: Is this *exactly* the code you tested? How can you tell that it is _print that works and not _print_func? (They try to print exactly the same thing.)

Comment: @prl Yes. I first tried to call only `_print` and then I added the call to `_print_func`

Comment: If your assembler gives a warning you should consider looking into it. You typoed the `syscall`instruction in 2.asm. `sycall` should be `syscall` . `sycall` got treated as a label (per the warning NASM should have given you) so that's why nothing happened. No `syscall` was done in `2.asm`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, Im aware of that.  But I thought it did not matter in the case. Anyway the functions content are perfectly identical.

Comment: They are not perfectly identical. One has a typo

Comment: It does matter regarding reading too many bytes. If you define memory with 1 byte and read 8 bytes with an instruction it will read whatever 7 bytes follow the first from memory. You only luck out because the following bytes had 0's in them.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, yes, exactly. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So did you fix the typo of `sycall` and change it to `syscall`? I'm assuming that resolves the issue you are seeing. The issue wasn't linking at all.

Comment: It's good that you had the typo in syscall, because otherwise it might have worked and you wouldn't have learned about the 1 / 8 byte thing.

Comment: You can load 1 byte memory into 64b register by either extending it with zeroed bits: `movzx edx,byte [mem]` (`edx` is enough, it will clear upper 32 bits too, it's special feature of x86-64), or sign-extend it: `movsx rdx,byte [mem]` (here `rdx` must be target, if you really want full 64b signed value).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes I fixed the typo, but the function linked from another object file still does not work. Btw, I noticed that if I change `.rodata` to `.data` (So `section .data` declared in two modules) both functions does not work.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you very much. I just replaced my mistaken `mov` with `movzx rdx, byte [mem]` and suddenly it started working. Why? Looks as some magic

Comment: @MichaelPetch It seems the issue was about `movzx rdx, byte [mem]`. I fixed the typo and now it works fine.

Comment: Who knows why, use debugger to see how it is different, or at least `strace` to know what arguments went into system calls. And for `movzx` you can target `edx` only, that will clear upper 32 bits of `rdx` automatically. Assembly programmers are not wizard seeing into the machine, we just use debugger for everything, to verify all our assumptions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: NASM wouldn't warn about the `sycall` typo unless you used `-Worphan-labels`.  And St.Antario: using the same section for both files exposed the 8-byte-load bug because instead of zeros the upper the upper bytes of the length will come from the next string.  And BTW, there's no need to load the length from a `db`, you could define an assembler constant for it with `str_len equ $ - str`, so `mov edx, str_len` will assemble to a mov-immediate.

Comment: @PeterCordes :I have a stock Debian build of NASM 2.12.01 and without any parameters, it warned of the issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oops, thanks for checking.  Apparently `-Worphan-labels` is on by default now in my NASM 2.13 build, too.  That's definitely a good thing.  IDK if that's been the case for a long time.  (Just checked 2.11 in an old Ubuntu, and it's on by default there too.)  Maybe that's always been the case, and I just misread the documentation and thought it needed to be enabled manually :P